# Spotify Play Button - spotilocal.com Error - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: button, widget, spotify, playback

The integration of the Spotify Play Button widget, causes more then 29 errors on page load. The script (md.b6ade05.js) causes ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED errors, when trying to connect.

Is there a solution for this issue?

Screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 2):

That is how the Spotify Play Button tries to find the running Spotify webhelper to communicate with it, so there isn't any way to prevent those requests.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue and tried opening up my page in a private window, with extensions disabled - and it worked. Looks like an ad blocker is preventing connection ~